# How to filter out unavailable YouTube videos

Tags: youtube-javascript-api

Youtube API returns the list of videos:

```
var request = window.gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
    chart: 'mostPopular',
    videoCategoryId: 0,  // 1,2,10,15,17...
    pageToken: pageToken,
    regionCode: locale,
    type: 'video',
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status'
});
```

but not all videos can be played. I use iframe YT.Player for playing:

```
player = new YT.Player('video-player', {
  height: '480',
  width: '360',
  videoId: videoId,
  playerVars: {
    controls: 0,
    modestbranding: 1,
    enablejsapi: 1,
    rel: 0,
    showinfo: 0,
    disablekb: 1
  },
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
    'onError': onPlayerError
  }
});
```

Some videos from feeds cannot be played. How can I filter videos in feeds,  all videos from this list you can play?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be played"? Are they private, deleted, region-blocked etc.

Comment: I see the messages like "This video contains content from (WMG, ...). It is restricted from playback on certain sites. Watch on YouTube" on the video player screen.

Comment: For filtering videos I use 'regionCode'. I tried to use "safeSearch", "videoEmbeddable", "videoLicense", "videoSyndicated" filters with different parameters but it was not helped.